# Black Screen With just mouse

Tags: windows-7, windows, bios, mouse

I have an ACER Veriton. Desktop. 4 GB Ram and an Intel Processor. BIOS is American Megatrends. Version 2.15.1236. Whenever I start up my computer in the morning after logging in with the user password, instead of showing the desktop there will be this black screen with just a mouse cursor, Earlier i thought the explorer.exe isn't starting, so i Alt + Ctrl + Del to start Task manager and start a new task, so that i can start explorer.exe manually, but thats not the case, alt + ctrl + del does not work, then there is no option left for me to but wait, so if i wait for around 5-7 minutes, then the desktop shows up and the windows in normal. but this happens everymorning when i start up, and yes please , i checked my registry too, the value of shell is explorer.exe and also i tried to update my video card driver, but it says

> the best version is already installed.

.
But what i did notice is that if i leave my screen on the login screen for about 5-7 minutes it works completely fine and the desktop shows up as soon as i enter the password. but i have to wait for few minutes at the login screen. So i tried schedule start up so that it can start up before i enter my workplace and everything is loaded in place and i can use it directly. I tried the option in the bios saying

> Resume by RTC Alarm.

but this doesn't schedule start up my computer either. Please help

Comment: Your question is hard to understand as written. Can you try to organize it a bit better?

Comment: @DragonLord basically my system wont start immediately when i log in. there will be just black screen and mouse cursor and nothing works not even Alt Ctrl Del. then i have to wait for like 5 mins then desktop appears and everything starts normally.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't sound like a hardware problem if everything is functioning normally once startup completes. But, if you can't move the mouse cursor while the screen is black, it could very well point to hardware. I suspect software, particularly a third-party application such as anti-virus. I would begin troubleshooting this by removing programs from the startup.

There are a few ways to approach this.

1. Boot into safe mode to find out if you can log in normally.

   - If yes, move to #2.
   - If no, proceed.
   - Go into the device manager and look for problems (!).
   - If no issues in device manager, use [performance monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722148.aspx) to determine the problem.
2. While in safe mode, configure selective startup.

   - Open Run, and type msconfig.
   - Since this sounds like a work machine, I would recommend opening the startup tab and taking a screenshot of it then save it. Then you can restore these as close as possible to the original state.
   - Open the General tab.
   - Choose Selective startup.
   - Leave "Load system services" checked.
   - Uncheck "Load startup items."
3. Reboot the machine in normal mode.
4. Open msconfig again open the Startup tab.
5. Check the top entry.
6. Reboot.
7. Keep doing this until you've found the application causing the issue and either repair/reinstall it.

Another very handy tool is the event logs, more than likely you will find errors in there related to this problem that will help you fix it.